# CausesValidation="True" But Still Throwing Invalid Postback?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using html to create a datagrid and in the syntax for the grid, I have `CausesValidation="True"` BUT I still get the dreaded

> Invalid Postback

This is the code behind and if additional info is needed please let me know as I am pulling my hair out to resolve this issue.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (!IsPostBack)
  {
    Setup();
    GetThing1();  
    GetThing2();            
  }
}
private void GetThing1()
{
  this.gridInfo.Visible = true;
  //Run SQL Query to populate datagrid
  this.gridInfo.DataSource = DS;
  this.gridInfo.DataBind();
}
protected void gridInfo_ItemCommand(object source, DataGridCommandEventArgs e)
{
  if (!Page.IsPostBack)
  {
    if (e.CommandName == "AlterData")
    {
        Response.Redirect(".../pages/newpage.aspx");
    }
  }
}
private void GetThing2()
{
   if (userNameType == "Valid")
   {
      //Run this SQL Procedure
      //bind to datagrid
   }
   else
   {
      //Run this procedure
      //bind to datagrid
   }
}
```

And this is the HTML/CSS used for creating the grid itself

```
<asp:DataGrid runat="server" ID="gridInfo" AutoGenerateColumns="false"   CssClass="DataGrids"
GridLines="Both" ShowFooter="true" OnItemCommand="gridInfo_ItemCommand"  OnItemDataBound="gridInfo_ItemDataBound">
<ItemStyle CssClass="row" />
<FooterStyle CssClass="DataGridFooters" />
<HeaderStyle CssClass="DataGridHeaders" />
<Columns>
<asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="ID" ItemStyle-CssClass="Blue" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"
    HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-Width="40" Visible="true">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton ForeColor="White" ID="btnEdit" runat="server" CausesValidation="True"
            CssClass="BoldTextWhite" CommandName="Edit" Text='<%# Eval("ID") %>' CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>'>
        </asp:LinkButton>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateColumn>
<asp:BoundColumn DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" Visible="false">  </asp:BoundColumn>
<asp:BoundColumn DataField="first name" HeaderText="First"></asp:BoundColumn>
<asp:BoundColumn DataField="last name" HeaderText="Last"></asp:BoundColumn>
</asp:TemplateColumn>
```

Setup method below....

```
private void Setup()
{
  this.lblMessage.Text = "Please click an ID from the grid for further information";
}
```

And this message is thrown when I click one of the ids in gridinfo, which should launch a seperate page, not load any data to the grid so I am not sure why this error is displaying.

Comment: The `CausesValidation` property is unrelated to the invalid postback error, it just determines whether a change to the field fires validation controls

Comment: this sounds like an issue with you trying to bind the data before any other events are being called .. do you have any other events in your code than the ones that you are displaying currently..?

Comment: @MethodMan - Yes, I just double checked the code their was one additional method that is called on PageLoad...

Comment: @BenRobinson thank you for that info, I thought (in my limited knowledge) the two were related!

Answer (score 0):

Need more information, what exactly you are doing when you get this error. Also there is no code for your Setup() method. How is the postback event is fired, have you click on any control on the page?

Comment: the issue is thrown when I click an ID from the gridInfo - it should launch the seperate page, but it only throws the error

Comment: this is not an answer this should be a comment @MuhammadIdrees

Comment: @MethodMan, yes agreed. so should I delete it ?